# QuickBooks SDK: How to use the QBFC library (32-bits) within a 64-bit application

Tags: azure, azure-functions, 32bit-64bit, quickbooks, qbfc

I am currently developing a QuickBooks Desktop integration in .NET 8 and have created QuickBooks services using the QBFC16 library (QuickBooks Function Classes) for performing queries within the system. Unfortunately, QBFC16 is limited to 32-bit architecture, making it challenging to seamlessly integrate within a 64-bit environment. This is, from my understanding, the only way to interact with the Desktop version of QuickBooks, since the REST API is only for QuickBooks online.

During local testing, I can run the application on x86 from Visual Studio without any issues. However, the problem arises when attempting to run the integration within an Azure Function, as Azure Core Tools operate in 64-bit mode by default.

The encountered error is as follows:

`Error connecting to QuickBooks: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {51271FB0-43CE-46C0-97E0-F1205E99C594} failed due to the following error: 800700c1  is not a valid Win32 application. (0x800700C1).`

I have explored potential solutions, such as installing the 32-bit version of Azure Core Tools, but it seems that the 64-bit version takes precedence during runtime, likely due to my computer's architecture.

I am seeking advice on the most effective and scalable workaround for this situation. While I am aware of options like running the integration in a 32-bit VM or creating a Docker image for Azure Functions, I would appreciate guidance on whether there is a simpler solution or if there are alternative approaches that I might consider. I am also open to exploring options beyond Azure Functions if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

qbfc 16 is the first QB SDK that comes in 32 bit and 64 bit versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).